# Can i turn on usb debugging without touching the screen?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging

My phone working for a long time without problems. I go to sleep my phone is still working.I wake up and turn on my phone. The phone turned up but i can't write my PIN and my screen is almost not working. I thing the problem is with android and i don't know how to get in recovery mode to factory reset or installing new rom. I don't have turned on usb debugging .Is there a way to get usb debugging turn on without touching the screen ?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! We don't know the brand "My Phone", so specific help is hard to give (you should always name the device affected and the Android version it is running). See our corresponding tag-wikis for entering [recovery mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) and performing a [factory reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info).

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold power button to turn off the phone.
Find the combination to get into recovery (usually a combination of power and volume buttons). Once in recovery, The phone will most likely be connected in Debug mode.

If its not in debug mode, Then you need to flash a custom recovery(Voids the warranty in most cases).